# removeRows() and QPersistentModelIndex

Tags: c++, qt, model, qabstractitemmodel, qabstractlistmodel

I have implemented my own `QAbstractListModel` which is based on an `std::vector`. I now want to display the contents of this model in a `QGraphicsScene`. For this I have implemented my own `QGraphicsItem` which stores a `QPersistentModelIndex` as a pointer to the data.

I have implemented the `removeRows` method as follows:

```
bool VectorModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex& parent) {
    if (row + count < _vector.size()) {
        beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + count);
        _vector.erase(_vector.begin() + row, _vector.begin() + row + count);
        endRemoveRows();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Now since I erase some elements, the index of the following elements will change. Because of this the `QPersistentModelIndex` needs to be adjusted.

I have found the `changePersistentIndex()` method in `QAbstractItemModel` and I know that I can get all persistent indices with `persistentIndexList()`. However I don't know how to adjust the indices accordingly using this method. How can this be done?

Will changing these indices be enough to prevent `Invalid index` errors?

**Update**

I have changed the `removeRows()` with the enhancements of @Sebastian Lange, however it is still not working as expected and I receive `Invalid index` errors:

```
bool LabelModel::removeRows(int row, int count, const QModelIndex& parent) {
    Q_UNUSED(parent)
    if (row + count < _vector.size()) {
        beginRemoveRows(QModelIndex(), row, row + count);
        _vector.erase(_vector.begin() + row, _vector.begin() + row + count);
        endRemoveRows();

        auto pil = persistentIndexList();
        for(int i = 0; i < pil.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (i >= row + count) {
                changePersistentIndex(pil[i], pil[i-count]);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The emitted errors look like this (when removing the 7th element):

```
QAbstractItemModel::endRemoveRows:  Invalid index ( 7 , 1 ) in model QAbstractListModel(0x101559320)
QAbstractItemModel::endRemoveRows:  Invalid index ( 8 , 1 ) in model QAbstractListModel(0x101559320)
QAbstractItemModel::endRemoveRows:  Invalid index ( 9 , 1 ) in model QAbstractListModel(0x101559320)
QAbstractItemModel::endRemoveRows:  Invalid index ( 10 , 1 ) in model QAbstractListModel(0x101559320)
QAbstractItemModel::endRemoveRows:  Invalid index ( 6 , 1 ) in model QAbstractListModel(0x101559320)
```

Comment: Just decrease the row by one for every index following your removed element. Personally I do not like working with persistent indexes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to do so (see update) but still receive ``Invalid index`` errrors.

Answer (score 4):

Well, you do not need to fiddle with changePersistentIndex, calling beginRemoveRows and endRemoveRows will automatically update all the persistent indexes currently existing on the model. The only invalid QPersistentModelIndex you should have after removing rows are the index on rows which have been actually deleted